# R h20 neural network viewing predictions

Tags: r, neural-network, prediction

I am playing around with the neural network capabilities in the h20 library for the first time, and I'm wondering how I can view the predictions from my trained model.  Ideally I'd like to see all of the predictions in a data frame, or combine them with the test data frame so that I can see the prediction and actual for each row of data.  This is the code I ran to train and test the model:

```
NN_model<- h2o.deeplearning(
training_frame = train.hex, 
validation_frame = test.hex,
x = 18:20,
y = 17,
activation = "TanhWithDropout", 
epochs = 1, 
variable_importances = TRUE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out:

```
NP <- as.data.frame(h2o.predict(object=NN_model,newdata=test.hex))
```